# Using Std::allocator to alocate memory at specific adress

Tags: c++, allocator

Can std::allocator be used to allocate memory of a certain size at a specific address?

Comment: No, it can't.  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: To elaborate a bit, there "is" a way on most OS to do what you are asking, but anyone actually needing that would typically know how already. This makes it likely that what you are going in the wrong direction in the first place, and providing you with an answer without more context might just be letting you dig your hole further.

Comment: @Frank , I am working on the OS level and I need to allocate certain buffers at cetrian address for embedded application

Comment: "allocation" means requesting memory from the OS (or some other memory pool). If you want to construct objects in already accounted-for memory, then this is a completely different matter. You should clarify the question.

Comment: I am creating an OS-likish application and I would like to allocate memory at fixed address

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on the OS level and I need to allocate certain buffers at certain address for embedded application.

Allocation is the process of obtaining memory from the OS. Without an OS, or if you are writing the OS, you don't need to allocate the memory at all, you can just use it as is.

If you want to construct a typed buffer at that location, you can use `placement-new` to do this.

```
#include <new>

struct MyBufferType {
 //...
};

MyBufferType* buffer = reinterpret_cast<MyBufferType*>(0xdeadbee0);

void construct_buffer() {
  buffer = new (buffer) MyBufferType();
}
```